# Excluding object properties in Laravel nested relationships

Tags: laravel

is there a way, to exclude some properties from a related model in laravel?

My controller method looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return QuizQuestionGroup::inRandomOrder()
        ->with('questions.answers')
        ->first();
}
```

Every QuizQuestionGroup has some questions and then every question has some answers.

Every answer contains these properties: id, text, correct, timestamps.

How would I exclude the 'correct' property from every answer?

I know that this can be done with joins, but is there a more Laravel way to do it?

Comment: You mean to **hide/remove** 'correct' column?

Comment: have you tried: >with('questions.answers:'id, text, timestamps');?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by OMR, `select` only the columns that you need

```
return QuizQuestionGroup::inRandomOrder()
->with('questions:id,title', 'questions.answers:id,question_id,text')
->first();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first method doesn't work, because makeHidden() cannot be used on relationships. `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::makeHidden()`